# We say a binary string is special if it cannot be expressed as a concatenation of several identical smaller strings.

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

For example $101101101$ is not special, but $10101$ is. How many special strings are there of length $n$?

My approach: Total $= 2^n$.
Say $n$'s set of prime divisors (with $1$) are $p_0, p_1, p_2$...
Which gives me the answer = $2^n - 2^{p_0} - 2^{p_1} - 2^{p_2}$...
As an example, for $12$, we take $1, 2,3$ and we can say no of special binary stings $= 2^{12} - 2 - 4 - 8$

Is my solution correct?

The author suggested we use mobius inversion, how do we do this with mobius inversion?

Comment: I think you can solve this with inclusion-exclusion, which the Mobius function naturally encodes.

Comment: You need to look at all divisors of n. If you exclude strings of length 2 and length 3, then you overcount length 6. I hope you can see where inclusion-exclusion comes in .